# How to update Class Variable that is constantly changing

Tags: python

I am trying to update the end variable in my SuffixNode Class, automatically.  What I mean is I have created a SuffixNode in the following code, and I assigned the endIndex.end as the SuffixNode's end value.  Then I update the endIndex.end to 2.  However, when I print the (self.root.end) out after I updated the  endIndex.end value, the end value store in SuffixNode is still showing 1 rather than show the updated 2.

Can anyone provide me with a suggestion on how should I modify the code, so that when I update the endIndex.end, the end value store in the SuffixNode will also update automatically.

Thank you

Below is the code

class EndIndex:
    def **init**(self, endIndexValue):
        self.end = endIndexValue

```
class ActivePoint:
    def __init__(self, activeLength, activeNode, activeEdge, suffixCount):
        self.activeLength = activeLength
        self.activeNode = activeNode
        self.activeEdge = activeEdge
        self.suffixCount = suffixCount


class SuffixNode:
    def __init__(self, start, end, index = None):
        # Create a list storing all the possible english alphabet
        # This will be used to store the starting characte
        self.children = [None] * 87

        # The pointer to the other node via suffix link
        self.suffixLink = None

        # The index of the start and end of the substring
        self.index = index
        self.start = start
        self.end = end


class SuffixTree:
    def __init__(self):
        # Initiate Active Point Values the End Index Value
        activePoints = ActivePoint(0, 0, 0, 0)
        endIndex = EndIndex(0)

        print("AL: %d | AN: %d | AE: %d | ASC: %d | End: %d" % (activePoints.activeLength, activePoints.activeNode, activePoints.activeEdge, activePoints.suffixCount, endIndex.end))

        endIndex.end = 1

        print("AL: %d | AN: %d | AE: %d | ASC: %d | End: %d" % (activePoints.activeLength, activePoints.activeNode, activePoints.activeEdge, activePoints.suffixCount, endIndex.end))

        self.root = SuffixNode(0, endIndex.end)

        print(self.root.end)


        endIndex.end = endIndex.end + 1

        print("AL: %d | AN: %d | AE: %d | ASC: %d | End: %d" % (activePoints.activeLength, activePoints.activeNode, activePoints.activeEdge, activePoints.suffixCount, endIndex.end))

        print(self.root.end)


suffixTree = SuffixTree()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create `endIndex` in your code at all. And that's the only change that you need to make. So, your `SuffixTree` should be like that:

```
class SuffixTree:
    def __init__(self):
        # Initiate Active Point Values the End Index Value
        activePoints = ActivePoint(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.root = SuffixNode(0, 0)  #<---- defing root here with 0 as a start value for end

        print("AL: %d | AN: %d | AE: %d | ASC: %d | End: %d" % (activePoints.activeLength, activePoints.activeNode, activePoints.activeEdge, activePoints.suffixCount, self.root.end)) #<---- use self.root.end instead

        self.root.end = 1  #<---- use self.root.end instead of endIndex.end

        print("AL: %d | AN: %d | AE: %d | ASC: %d | End: %d" % (activePoints.activeLength, activePoints.activeNode, activePoints.activeEdge, activePoints.suffixCount, self.root.end)) #<---- use self.root.end instead

        print(self.root.end)


        self.root.end += 1  #<---- use self.root.end instead of endIndex.end

        print("AL: %d | AN: %d | AE: %d | ASC: %d | End: %d" % (activePoints.activeLength, activePoints.activeNode, activePoints.activeEdge, activePoints.suffixCount, self.root.end)) #<---- use self.root.end

        print(self.root.end)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate `SuffixNode` to `self.root`, `self.root.end` is assigned *the current value of* `endIndex.end`. `self.root.end` is not a reference to `endIndex.end`, it's just a duplicate of the integer that `endIndex.end` contained at the assignment. Now, if you assigned `self.root = endEndex`, `self.root.end` would be shown to change when `endIndex.end` changes.

Comment: Thank you. After making the changes to my code, it works perfectly.